# stopping of event-viewer services, and performing malacious activities

Tags: windows-7, event-viewer

what will happen if i shutdown the windows event log services. I know it will stop event viewer. My question is will this activity be logged somewhere. if yes, then where?. and where will be the activities performed after this will be logged. Thanks

Comment: If you shut down Windows logging system, Windows won't log anything, so your question makes little sense.  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: i want everything to be logged in. so even if user shuts down "windows event log" services, i should be able to track the activities

Comment: Make them unable to stop Event Log service.

Comment: Like @gronostaj said. More generally, don't give administrator access to people you don't trust. That holds on all systems.

Comment: if we disable the "windows event log" service, will that be logged somewhere?? if yes where and if no then how can i find that